# Push Notifications don't appear on devices

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I have already written a lot of code in which I set notifications and try to send a notification from a user to another but now here is my problem, there isn't any notification that appears on the other user's device. The app doesn't crash and I have don't have build failed so I really don't know where I am wrong. Thanks in advance for your answers, here's my code...

// Parts about push notifications in AppDelegate.swift

```
static let NOTIFICATION_URL = "https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send"
static var DEVICEID = String()
static let SERVERKEY = "AAAAuIcRiYI:APA91bHA8Q4IJBG9dG4RY9YOZ3v4MlcVZjmYs3XhiMY3xpQm3bTSjrINUiImaE0t17Y6mghR2vN1ezJTMSVFmHlgOUBX8KQZEckgwCkc1tlMdpm_UjxobmrHf3GbvwrKtHVZsJR-v1GG"

#available(iOS 10.0, *){
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        // Request Autorization.
        let option : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert,.badge,.sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: option) { (bool, err) in
        }
    }
    else{
        let settings : UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert,.badge,.sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    guard  let newToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token() else {return}
    AppDelegate.DEVICEID = newToken
    connectToFCM()
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let notification =  response.notification.request.content.body
    print(notification)
    completionHandler()
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    guard let token = InstanceID.instanceID().token() else {return}

    AppDelegate.DEVICEID = token
    print(token)
    connectToFCM()
}

func connectToFCM()
{
    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
}
```

// Parts about notifications in messages.swift, I call this function after the user sends a message in way that the person who receives the message receives at the same time a notification.

```
fileprivate func setupPushNotification(fromDevice:String)
{

    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let device = value?["device"] as? String ?? ""

    guard let message = self.authorText else {return}
    let title = "You received a new message !"
    let body = "from \(message)"
    let toDeviceID = device
    var headers:HTTPHeaders = HTTPHeaders()

    headers = ["Content-Type":"application/json","Authorization":"key=\(AppDelegate.SERVERKEY)"

    ]
    let notification = ["to":"\(toDeviceID)","notification":["body":body,"title":title,"badge":1,"sound":"default"]] as [String:Any]

    Alamofire.request(AppDelegate.NOTIFICATION_URL as URLConvertible, method: .post as HTTPMethod, parameters: notification, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        print(response)
    }
    })

}
```

Comment: Double check that `\(toDeviceID)` or any other one like this are not producing `Optional(toDeviceID)` .

Comment: Make sure that you're on the latest Firebase 5.18.0 with FirebaseInstanceID 3.7.0

Comment: `["body": "from Sean Conlan", "badge": 1, "sound": "default", "title": "You received a new message !"]]
SUCCESS: {
    "canonical_ids" = 0;
    failure = 1;
    "multicast_id" = 4813942347357942695;
    results =     (
                {
            error = InvalidApnsCredential;
        }
    );
    success = 0;
}
2019-03-08 19:58:25.388270+0100 onenseven[8421:279462] [Assert] Cannot be called with asCopy = NO on non-main thread.` I checked that toDeviceID wasn't optional but it didn't change mush so I printed the notification i got this in the Debug area @MwcsMac

Comment: How can I check that I'm on the latest versions? Thanks for your answer. @PaulBeusterien

Comment: Check the contents of Podfile.lock